# Airflow web-ui Could not read served logs

Tags: docker, logging, airflow

I am running Airflow 2.6.1 locally, via docker container, and I am having issues displaying the task logs in the web-ui.

I get the following message:

> *** Could not read served logs: Client error '404 NOT FOUND' for url 'http://f691dce3682f:8793/log/dag_id=file_transfer_DAVIS011_PD/run_id=manual__2023-06-02T09:25:04+00:00/task_id=ftp_transfer_remote2airflow/attempt=1.log'
> For more information check: https://httpstatuses.com/404

Anyone has an idea of what I need to change to have the logs readable in the web-ui?

[image]

I have the following log config in `airflow.cfg`

```
[logging]
base_log_folder = /opt/airflow/logs
remote_logging = False
remote_log_conn_id =
delete_local_logs = False
google_key_path =
remote_base_log_folder =
remote_task_handler_kwargs =
encrypt_s3_logs = False
logging_level = INFO
celery_logging_level = 
fab_logging_level = WARNING
logging_config_class =
colored_console_log = True
colored_log_format = [%%(blue)s%%(asctime)s%%(reset)s] {%%(blue)s%%(filename)s:%%(reset)s%%(lineno)d} %%(log_color)s%%(levelname)s%%(reset)s - %%(log_color)s%%(message)s%%(reset)s
colored_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.colored_log.CustomTTYColoredFormatter
log_format = [%%(asctime)s] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
simple_log_format = %%(asctime)s %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
dag_processor_log_target = file
dag_processor_log_format = [%%(asctime)s] [SOURCE:DAG_PROCESSOR] {%%(filename)s:%%(lineno)d} %%(levelname)s - %%(message)s
log_formatter_class = airflow.utils.log.timezone_aware.TimezoneAware
secret_mask_adapter =
task_log_prefix_template =
log_filename_template = dag_id={{ ti.dag_id }}/run_id={{ ti.run_id }}/task_id={{ ti.task_id }}/{%% if ti.map_index >= 0 %%}map_index={{ ti.map_index }}/{%% endif %%}attempt={{ try_number }}.log
log_processor_filename_template = {{ filename }}.log
dag_processor_manager_log_location = /opt/airflow/logs/dag_processor_manager/dag_processor_manager.log
task_log_reader = task
extra_logger_names =
worker_log_server_port = 8080trigger_log_server_port = 8080
file_task_handler_new_folder_permissions = 0o777
file_task_handler_new_file_permissions = 0o666
```

Comment: I believe that all that was need was to chnage the rights in the logs dir `sudo chmod a+rw  logs/* -R`